# UnityContainer() LoadConfiguration not found

Tags: unity-container

I have this code:

```
1: IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
2: container.LoadConfiguration();
```

Line 1 works, but line 2 not. LoadConfiguration is not found as a member.
I think, i have register all unity-dlls. Why is LoadConfiguration() not found?

Comment: I too had this question too and intellisense did not tell me that I needed to add Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration. So, actually, this question did help me! ;) Thanks, Robert Harvey, for the answer. :)

Comment: Add this to your using area : "using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;" of your file.  The extension is found in a another namespace.  (This worked with version 2.0.414.0 )

Answer (score 21):

`LoadConfiguration()` is not a [member of IUnityContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.iunitycontainer_members.aspx).  You must be thinking of some other class or interface.  Perhaps [this one?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.configuration.unitycontainerextensions_members%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

`IUnityContainer` is in the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` namespace, but the `LoadConfiguration()` extension method lives in the [Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.configuration%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) namespace.  Have you added that namespace to your code?

Comment: I found the solutuion, I have reinstall Unity Block with newest Version, it works now.

Answer (score 8):

I believe in the latest version of Unity 5.9.3, Microsoft.Practices.Unity dlls are not part of the nuget. You'd have to install another package from nuget '[Unity.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Configuration/5.9.0/)'. Its an open source package offered by Unity. As of today, Unity Configuration latest version is 5.9.0.

Answer (score 4):

Not only

**Unity.Configuration** package should be installed

but also

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
```

should be declared at top of the cs file.